# close button click of jquery modal popup

Tags: jquery, button, click

I am using jquery modal poup to open a page (example from parent page,a.spx, iam opening the child page,b.aspx.)

Following is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $("[id$='lnkbtn']").click(function() {
            var str = $(this).attr("details");
            var page = ('../b.aspx?no=' + str);
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, height: 500, width: 900});
            $dialog.dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to refresh my parent page when the user clicks the close button(x) on the modal popup (I.E b.aspx).

I went thru the following link but i am not getting the expected op.

http://jsfiddle.net/XM2FH/

Following is the modified code based on my requirment.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            open: function() //runs every time this dialog is opened
            {
                //var $dialog = $(this);
                var page = ('../../a/bc.aspx');
                var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, height: 650, width: 1000 });
                if (!$dialog.data('titleCloseBound')) {
                    $dialog
                    .data('titleCloseBound', true) //flag as already bound
                    .closest('div.ui-dialog') //traverse up to the outer dialog wrapper
                        .find('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close') //search within it for the X
                            .bind('click', function(e) //bind it
                            {
                                alert('hi');
                                e.preventDefault();
                               __doPostBack('', '');
                            });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
  close: function( event, ui ) {
    __doPostBack('', '');
  }
});
```

your second code is wrong and misleading.try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("[id$='lnkbtn']").click(function() {
        var str = $(this).attr("details");
        var page = ('../b.aspx?no=' + str);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
            .dialog({ 
                modal: true,
                height: 500,
                width: 900,
                close:function(){
                    window.location.reload();//or your __doPostBack()
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: the reason is iam opening a webpage in modal popup

Comment: i dont know what exactly __doPostBack('', ''); dose but i updated your fiddle page and the close event works just fine, i dont know what elese you what?

Comment: __doPostBack('', ''); is for postback. pls tell me what changes u made in my code so that i can jsut paste it.

Comment: i just added the close event

Comment: on x click, i can close the modal popup but what i want is to refresh the parent page which is not happening if i put my .aspx page.if i put a div, its working fine..

Comment: what i mean is if i uncomment the follwoing line and paste a div with id dialog it works fine var $dialog = $(this);

Comment: so u dont have any element with id '#dialog' in your page?

Comment: yes i have, please check my code, its there, the problem is jquery cant understand the page details what i am calling.i feel its simple but somehow i am not getting the expected op

Comment: var page = ('../../a/bc.aspx');
                var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, height: 650, width: 1000 });

Comment: if i put this var $dialog = $(this); and <div id="dialog"  title="Dialog Title"> I'm in a dialog</div> rather than 
this  var page = ('../../a/bc.aspx');
                var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, height: 650, width: 1000 }); it works fine,

Comment: ok i feel its something to do with my second code not the first one; the first one works fine; its used to open jquery modal popup

Comment: u know what iam looking for??? on my jquery modal popup i have a x button, on click of this button i want to post back the parent page...